# Firebase 'child_changed' listener understanding

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to grab real-time changes from Firebase on the status of a question in the lifecycle of my system. My `child_changed` event is interacting differently than I was expecting, so I am not sure if I am using it right.

I want to grab the new change to the `questionStatus` variable, so that if another user on the system changes the variable on the database, the updates will be seen real time for both users. My Firebase DB is setup like so:

```
-/questions
     -/ID1234567890
          -/title
          -/messages
               -/ID1234567890
               -/ID2345678901
```

**'child_changed' call:**

```
fire.database().ref('/questions/' + this.state.questionId + '/questionStatus').on('child_changed', snap => {
      this.setState({
        questionStatus: (snap.val().questionStatus),
      })
      console.log("CHANGED!")
    })
```

The above code is how I think it should work, but I can never get the console.log to display as intended. By just removing `questionStatus` from the `ref()` (as outlined in the code below), the event triggers whenever I add a new message to the question (for chat), and seems to be causing a loading error. Am I misunderstanding firebase or is deeper in my code? Maybe this has to with lifecycle of component? I have tried placing it everywhere to no avail, but currently have it in `componentWillMount()`. Let me know what you think, thanks!

```
fire.database().ref('/questions/' + this.state.questionId).on('child_changed', snap => {
      this.setState({
        questionStatus: (snap.val().questionStatus),
      })
      console.log("CHANGED!")
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my research, I didn't full understand `setState()` fully, not knowing that the state can only be updated async, not sync. Knowing this, I just implemented a feature informing the user that the status has changed and to click a button to reload. Not ideal, but it will work for now.

I also tested to exclude children with a specific key (`messages`).

So my new code looks like this:

```
fire.database().ref('/questions/' + this.state.questionId).on('child_changed', snap => {
      // Ignore if messages are being added to the ticket
      if(snap.key !== 'messages'){
        this.setState({
          questionStatus: (snap.val().questionStatus),
          questionTags: (snap.val().questionTags),
          question
        })
      }
    })
```